# How can I update the array of objects from a fetch response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, setstate

I tried a lot of things based on the other questions, but I didnt figured it how to do it.

I have this array in my component constructor:

```
 testDependeciesArr:[]
```

When the user clicks on button "test dependencies" of my react component I call this function:

```
testDependencies() {
    axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_HOST + '/testDependencies')
      .then(resp => {
        this.setState(
          { testDependeciesArr: how to update this Array  }
          )

      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

That function makes a request to nodejs and it returns me this:

```
{0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}}
    0:
    responseTime: "21ms"
    responseStatus: "OK"

    1:
    responseTime: "2739ms"
    statusText: "OK"

    2:
    responseError: {message: "request to http:url failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 100.100.100.100:80", type: "system", errno: "ECONNREFUSED", code: "ECONNREFUSED"}
    responseTime: "10ms"
```

So, how can I update the array testDependeciesArr with the 3 objects that I get from the node response?

This table should be updated when I set the state:

```
API  Response Time  StatusDetail
API1    21ms          OK
API2    2739ms        OK
API3    21ms        request to http:url failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 100.100.100.100:80", type: "system", errno: "ECONNREFUSED", code: "ECONNREFUSED
```

Comment: Have you tried using
 `axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_HOST + '/testDependencies')
      .then(resp => {
        this.setState(
          { testDependeciesArr: resp  }
          )

      })` this? as per my suggestion, this would work.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd I tried it, but my table is not updated with the response (I edited my question to show the table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of `Object.values()`:

```js
const res = {
  0: {
      responseTime: "21ms",
      responseStatus: "OK"
     },

 1:  {
      responseTime: "2739ms",
      statusText: "OK"
     },

 2: {
    responseError: {
      message: "request to http:url failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 100.100.100.100:80", type: "system",
      errno: "ECONNREFUSED", code: "ECONNREFUSED"},
    responseTime: "10ms"
    }
};


console.log(Object.values(res));
```

So, in your code:

```
testDependeciesArr: Object.values(resp)
```

Comment: in this case, I keep the constructor like this: `testDependenciesArr:[ ]`?

Comment: You do not need any constructor, mate. The state property will be replaced even if it holds _null_ , _undefined_ or whatever

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
testDependencies() {
    axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_HOST + '/testDependencies')
      .then(resp => {

        this.setState(
          { testDependeciesArr: Object.values(resp)}
          )

      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

Comment: what's the difference from my response to the OP ?

Comment: How can I get those data in my frontend? It should be somethinkg like `props.testResult[index].responseTime` ?

Comment: @S_A yes, exactly you need to fetch data using index and key.